# What is the significance of jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize in jetty.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, webserver, jetty, application-server

I am upgrading jetty version from jetty-9.4.14.v20181114 to jetty-9.4.24.v20191120.
and  attribute(jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize in jetty.xml) value is decreased(4096 to 1024).

Is there any performance reason or some other reasons for reducing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty is open source. So the question can easily be answered by following these steps:

1. Find the [source code](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.jetty/developer)
2. Find the [location of the change in the source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blame/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty.xml#L50)
3. See [commit message](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/c336616c9655b4fba5023d6496d7633461619927) with hopefully linked [issue/bug report](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2709)

This leads to [Jetty issue #2709](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2709), [comment by Greg Wilkins](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2709#issuecomment-551240205):

> We have some feedback that 4kb is frequently wasting memory. Trading
>   the PR, it seams that 1k would have been sufficient, so we should
>   probably dial back to that.